# Unclear perl script execution

Tags: perl

Executon of my perl scipt is unclear to me. It doesn't execute line-per-line, and I don't know why?

Code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
#line 200 "Level Check"
print "\n1";
$level=554;
if($level > 550){
warn "Level Higher Than 550 ($level)";
}
print "\n2";
```

Output:

> Level Higher Than 550 (554) at Level Check line 203.
>
> 1
>
> 2

Why doesn't it output:

> 1
>
> Level Higher Than 550 (554) at Level Check line 203.
>
> 2

Comment: s/b #!/usr/bin/perl (note you missed the leading '/')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `STDOUT` is buffered. The warning is coming through `STDERR` before `STDOUT` gets flushed.

By default `warn()` goes to `STDERR` and `print` goes to `STDOUT`. In your current code, you're seeing `STDERR` being flushed prior to `STDOUT`

You can change that behavior by adding the following at the top:

```
select STDERR; $| = 1;
select STDOUT; $| = 1;
```

That sets `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to be unbuffered and flush on every print.

Comment: You might want to note that (by default) `print` uses the `STDOUT` file descriptor, and `warn` uses the `STDERR` descriptor.  Otherwise this explanation has a bit of a gap.  :)

Comment: I'll edit, but that was already implied "The warning is coming through STDERR"

Comment: And you may prefer using `use IO::Handle; STDERR->autoflush; STDOUT->autoflush;` if you don't want to keep track of what `$|` does.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, one of your problems IO-buffering.

An other problem is, that our output (after fixing the buffering-problem) will be:

```
 \n
 1Level Higher Than 550 (554) at Level Check line 203.\n
 2
```

instead of:

```
 1\n
 Level Higher Than 550 (554) at Level Check line 203.\n
 2\n
```

which I'm guessing you expect. ('\n' added for clarity). The reason might be obvious...

Paul

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's because of the buffering.  Both STDOUT and STDERR are connect to a terminal (AKA tty) and output to it is buffered until a newline; then it is printed.  You have:

```
print "\n1";
```

which means the 1 will be buffered until the next newline.  Had you written:

```
print "1\n";
```

It would have been printed out right away.